# Splitting a string in substrings and putting those in a String []

Tags: java, string, arrays

So I have a string which i'm splitting up in substrings. Everyone of those substrings should become an element of a new String array.

so far I have this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (isr);

    System.out.println("String: ");
    String s = in.readLine();


    String [] rij = new String [s.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {      
        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ' || i==0){
            String temp = s.substring(i,s.indexOf(' ',i+1));
            rij [i] = temp;

        }

    }
```

If my input is: "Hello World."
my String array should become {Hello, World.}

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -33
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
    at CyclischPermuteren.main(CyclischPermuteren.java:34)
```

I don't know how to solve this because I can't figure out what I should use as length for my String array since the amount of substring needed to be made is unknown and need to use that string array in a static method later on.

Comment: Any reasons that you don't want to use the `split` method ?

Comment: also array representation should be ["Hello", "World."] not {Hello, World.}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you tried to do is:

```
String[] rij = new String[s.length()];

int j = 0; // To keep index in the array

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) != ' ') { // When is not space, add character to 'temp'     
        temp += s.charAt(i);
    }
    else { // If it is space, add temp to array and reset 'temp'
        rij[j++] = temp;
        temp = "";
    }
}

rij[j] = temp; // Add last word

for (String s1: rij)
    if (s1 != null)
       System.out.println(s1);
```

**Output:**

```
String: 
Welcome to StackOverflow, user3173758
Welcome
to
StackOverflow,
user3173758
```

**Note:**

Since you are creating an array `rij` with the maximum length possible, you are getting some `null`. If you want to avoid this, you could try using an `ArrayList` and its `add()` method. Read more about it in [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 2):

Because when `i` is equal to `s.length()-1` (the last element in your loop condition) you are trying to get a `substring` of `s` which goes to `i+1` which is essentially (at this point) `s.length()` which is out of bounds.

This is because if an array is size 10 then it's last element is at 9 (as it starts at 0).  So if you try to access `s.length()` you are trying to access (in my example) item 10 in an array that ends at 9.

Comment: Actually when it's equal to `s.length() - 1` `i+1` will be out of bounds.

Comment: Worth mentioning that arrays in Java are *0-based* (Smarty pants 2).

Comment: Wouldn't that be Smarty Pants++?

Comment: No, that won't compile ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the String method `split()`?

```
String[] parts = s.split("");

System.out.println(parts[0]);
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (isr);

  System.out.println("String: ");
  String s = in.readLine(); 

  String [] rij = s.split(" "); // asumming split should be done on spaces.
}
```

Check out the String's [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method